# Shouldn't the FB share button point to a better site description?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I'm not sure if this is a proper place to ask but I can't write to "contact us" link, it points to a nonexistent email address...

Basically, this is what I see when I click on the FB button.

[image]

I think it's quite misleading.

Comment: Do you mean `team+russian@stackexchange.com` isn't a real address? I assure you it is; we've received emails from there several times.

Comment: @Aarthi Some mail clients get twitchy at the `+` even though it's entirely legit.

Comment: @Miro Are you trying to share `http://russian.stackexchange.com/users/login` ? If so, then that's why you're getting that description; attempting to share a question or user profile should trigger a different description.

Comment: @Aarthi Aha, so this is the right address. When I click at the link in Chrome, it opens Gmail with "team russian...", I guess Gmail tries to be smarter than necessary

Answer (score 2):

We have no control over what Facebook pulls from the URL when sharing a page. In this case, it looks like the page was cached while the site was still in private beta... and should hopefully right itself in a few days.

Comment: Yes, this seems plausible.